# Mailx UNIX command removes line spaces from the attachment file

Tags: unix, mailx

I am trying to send a file in attachement, using mailx UNIX command.

Problem is, it changes the file, It removes the line spaces from the file and all the row comes in the same line.

```
(cat "tu"
 uuencode /gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_FOA_RMBHUB/"GL_CAP_ERROR_20150522.txt" "L_CAP_ERROR_20150522.txt"
) | mailx -s "EMAIL_SUBJECT" "person@email.om"
```

How to fix this.

Comment: What line endings do the files use?  Just newlines?  Newlines and carriage returns?  How is the output being rendered?  HTML or text?

Comment: It is a normal file with just newlines. I am sending the file with above code.

Comment: How are you *viewing* the email?  Is it being rendered as text or as HTML?

Comment: I am downloading the file attached in the mail and opening in the notepad.

Comment: What happens if you open it in wordpad? Notepad needs DOS line endings to display correctly. Wordpad is more adapted to multi-platform files.

Comment: Can you show us one line from the correct version of the file and the incorrect version?

Comment: if i paste 1 line from each, it will come as same....

Comment: Are you running `uudecode` to decode the file on the reading side, or is some other piece of software doing the decoding for you?